# How to create Ads Impressions System in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder

I'm creating an ads impression system.
I'm doing it like this. **is there any better way to do this?**

```
array:19 [▼
      0 => "24127"
      1 => "24126"
      2 => "24125"
      3 => "24124"
      4 => "24123"
      5 => "24122"
      6 => "24121"
      7 => "24120"
      8 => "24119"
      9 => "24118"
      10 => "122283"
      11 => "122282"
      12 => "18144"
      13 => "22950"
      14 => "134154"
      15 => "23064"
      16 => "14397"
      17 => "218105"
      18 => "21489"
    ]

foreach($data as $impress => $impressid){       
    $impRecord = DB::table("adsimpressions")->where([
                ['ad_id','=',$impressid->page_id.$impressid->id],
                ['date','=',date("d-m-Y")]
            ])->first();
        if(isset($impRecord->id) and is_object($impRecord)){
            DB::table("adsimpressions")->where("id",$impRecord->id)->increment('impressions');
        }else{
            DB::table("adsimpressions")->insert([
                'ad_id' =>$impressid->page_id.$impressid->id,
                'impressions' =>1,
                'date' => date("d-m-Y")
            ]);
        }
    }
```

I think this method make my page slow.. yours suggestion are important for me

Answer (score 1):

I am suggesting to you read Laravel Collection

```
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods
```

1: Fetch all the record of  `adsimpressions` table and store into in Laravel Collection Facade

2: Instead this Query

```
DB::table("adsimpressions")->where([
            ['ad_id','=',$impressid->page_id.$impressid->id],
            ['date','=',date("d-m-Y")]
        ])->first();
```

U can fetch record to your collection using laravel Collection where Method

```
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-where
```

Your DB connection is minimized and this method makea your page spead high